# Is the given Graph a tree? Faster than below approach -

Tags: python, time-complexity

I was given a question during an interview and although my answer was accepted at the end they wanted a faster approach and I went blank..

Question :

Given an undirected graph, can you see if it's a tree? If so, return true and false otherwise.

A tree:

```
    A - B
        |
        C - D
```

not a tree:

```
     A
    / \
   B - C
  /
 D
```

You'll be given two parameters: n for number of nodes, and a multidimensional array of edges like such: [[1, 2], [2, 3]], each pair representing the vertices connected by the edge.

Note:Expected space complexity : O(|V|)
The array edges can be empty

Here is My code: 105ms

```
def is_graph_tree(n, edges):
  nodes = [None] * (n + 1)

  for i in range(1, n+1):
    nodes[i] = i

  for i in range(len(edges)):
    start_edge = edges[i][0]
    dest_edge = edges[i][1]

    if nodes[start_edge] != start_edge:
      start_edge = nodes[start_edge]

    if nodes[dest_edge] != dest_edge:
      dest_edge = nodes[dest_edge]

    if start_edge == dest_edge:
      return False

    nodes[start_edge] = dest_edge

  return len(edges) <= n - 1
```

Comment: You don't have to build the tree.  If the pairs are sorted (so A < B), then if any node is in the right side twice, you have a loop.  Do people really ask this kind of question in interviews?  What does this prove?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes they do :)  this was a shared session in a Codility platform

Comment: If the code is supposed to work for connected graphs only, then the last line `return len(edges) <= n - 1` is all that is needed, since the only connected graphs satisfying this condition are trees. For graphs that are not necessarily connected, this code will not work in general. Try e.g. a graph with 6 vertices and edges `[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[5,6]]`.

Comment: Could you fix your indentations.  I tried to test your is_graph_tree function but couldn't make it work (for `[[1,2],[1,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]`)

Comment: Your code fails for example `is_graph_tree(4, [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3]])`, returning `True`. Hard to believe that that was accepted, that the interviewer didn't immediately realize you were trying to write union-find and clearly didn't do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach this from the perspective of tree leaves.  Every leaf node in a tree will have exactly one edge connected to it.  So, if you count the number of edges for each nodes, you can get the list of leaves (i.e. the ones with only one edge).

Then, take the linked node from these leaves and reduce their edge count by one (as if you were removing all the leaves from the tree.  That will give you a new set of leaves corresponding to the parents of the original leaves.  Repeat the process until you have no more leaves.

*[EDIT] checking that the number of edges is N-1 eliminiates the need to do the multi-root check because there will be another discrepancy (e.g. double link, missing node) in the graph if there are multiple 'roots' or a disconnected subtree*

If the graph is a tree, this process should eliminate all nodes from the node counts (i.e. they will all be flagged as leaves at some point).

Using the Counter class (from collections) will make this relatively easy to implement:

```
from collections import Counter

def isTree(N,E):
    if N==1 and not E: return True                # root only is a tree
    if len(E) != N-1:  return False               # a tree has N-1 edges
    counts  = Counter(n for ab in E for n in ab)  # edge counts per node
    if len(counts) != N : return False            # unlinked nodes
    while True:
        leaves = {n for n,c in counts.items() if c==1} # new leaves
        if not leaves:break
        for a,b in E:                             # subtract leaf counts
            if counts[a]>1 and b in leaves: counts[a] -= 1
            if counts[b]>1 and a in leaves: counts[b] -= 1
        for n in leaves: counts[n] = -1           # flag leaves in counts
    return all(c==-1 for c in counts.values())    # all must become leaves
```

output:

```
G = [[1,2],[1,3],[4,5],[4,6]]
print(isTree(6,G)) # False (disconnected sub-tree)

G = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[5,6]]
print(isTree(6,G)) # False (doubly linked node 3)

G = [[1,2],[2,6],[3,4],[5,1],[2,3]]
print(isTree(6,G)) # True

G = [[1,2],[2,3]]
print(isTree(3,G)) # True

G = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
print(isTree(4,G)) # True

G = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,5],[2,4]]
print(isTree(6,G)) # False (missing node)
```

*Space complexity is O(N) because the counts dictionary has one entry per node(vertex) with an integer as value.  Time complexity will be O(ExL) where E is the number of edges and L is the number of levels in the tree. The worts case time is O(E^2) for a tree where all parents have only one child node.  However, since the initial condition is for E to be less than V, the worst case will actually be O(V^2)*

*Note that this algorithm makes no assumption on edge order or numerical relationships between node numbers. The root (last node to be made a leaf) found by this algorithm is not necessarily the only possible root given that, unless the nodes have an implicit cardinality relationship (or edges have an order), there could be ambiguous scenarios:*

```
 [1,2],[2,3],[2,4]  could be:

         1                 2            3
         |_2        OR     |_1     OR   |_2
           |_3             |_3            |_1
           |_4             |_4            |_4
```

*If a cardinality relationship between node numbers or an order of edges can be relied upon, the algorithm could potentially be made more time efficient (because we could easily determine which node is the root and start from there).*

[EDIT2] Alternative method using groups.

When the number of edges is N-1, if the graph is a tree, all nodes should be reachable from any other node.  This means that, if we form groups of reachable nodes for each node and merge them together based on the edges, we should end up with a single group after going through all the edges.

Here is the modified function based on that approach:

```
def isTree(N,E):
    if N==1 and not E: return True                # root only is a tree
    if len(E) != N-1:  return False               # a tree has N-1 edges
    groups = {n:[n] for ab in E for n in ab}      # each node in its own group 
    if len(groups) != N : return False            # unlinked nodes
    for a,b in E:
        groups[a].extend(groups[b])               # merge groups
        for n in groups[b]: groups[n] = groups[a] # update nodes' groups
    return len(set(map(id,groups.values()))) == 1 # only one group when done
```

*Given that we start out with fewer edges than nodes and that group merging will consume at most 2x a group size (so also < N), the space complexity will remain O(V).  The time complexity will also be O(V^2) at for the worts case scenarios*

Comment: Just love it when someone goes this deep to explain something .. this is a neat approach & it does make more sense!!

Comment: @moin1010 This doesn't make sense at all. Your question asks for *"Faster than below approach"* but you accepted an answer that's much slower?

Comment: its because of the effort and time he put to explain how to approach this from a different perspective..@KellyBundy

Answer (score 1):

Tim Roberts has posted a candidate solution, but this will work in the case of disconnected subtrees:

```py
import queue

def is_graph_tree(n, edges):
    # A tree with n nodes has n - 1 edges.
    if len(edges) != n - 1:
        return False

    # Construct graph.
    graph = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    
    for first_vertex, second_vertex in edges:
        graph[first_vertex].append(second_vertex)
        graph[second_vertex].append(first_vertex)
    
    # BFS to find edges that create cycles.
    # The graph is undirected, so we can root the tree wherever we want.
    visited = set()
    q = queue.Queue()
    q.put((0, None))
    
    while not q.empty():
        current_node, previous_node = q.get()
        if current_node in visited:
            return False
        
        visited.add(current_node)
        for neighbor in graph[current_node]:
            if neighbor != previous_node:
                q.put((neighbor, current_node))
    
    # Only return true if the graph has only one connected component.
    return len(visited) == n
```

This runs in `O(n + len(edges))` time.

Comment: your code is actually 0.08 seconds slower than Tim's code :) but cool beans!

Comment: In my experience, interviewers tend not to care about small time deltas like this. They usually tend to care more about asymptotic time complexity. But fair enough.

Comment: @moin1010 Does it matter that some nonsensical wrong code is faster?

Comment: @KellyBundy I agree  and I think my code is decent enough.. but when at the end when she asked me if it can be any faster/efficient i just had no clear approach and wanted to see how others feel about this..

Comment: @moin1010 Well, maybe your own code was slow. I can't tell, as I don't know your code. I know it's not the one you showed in the question, because you claim a runtime for it but it doesn't even compile. And even with imagined correct indentation it doesn't look correct, but again, it doesn't compile, so I can't even test it.

Comment: @KellyBundy, it's the way the editor here forces extra indentation .. I think i fixed it now - I copied the same code on my PyCharm panel and runs.. 106ms

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using a disjoint-set-union / union-find data structure:

```py
def is_graph_tree(n, edges):
    parent = list(range(n+1))
    size = [1] * (n + 1)
    for x, y in edges:
        # find x (path splitting)
        while parent[x] != x:
            x, parent[x] = parent[x], parent[parent[x]]
        # find y
        while parent[y] != y:
            y, parent[y] = parent[y], parent[parent[y]]
        if x == y:
            # Already connected
            return False
        # Union (by size)
        if size[x] < size[y]:
            x, y = y, x
        parent[y] = x
        size[x] += size[y]
    return True

assert not is_graph_tree(4, [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)])
assert is_graph_tree(6, [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (1, 6)])
```

The runtime is `O(V + E*InverseAckermannFunction(V))`, which better than `O(V + E * log(log V))`, so it's basically `O(V + E)`.

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need to know how many edges there are:

```
def is_graph_tree(n, edges):
    seen = set()
    for a,b in edges:
        b = max(a,b)
        if b in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(b)
    return True

a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
print(is_graph_tree(0,a))
b = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,4]]
print(is_graph_tree(0,b))
```

Now, this WON'T catch the case of disconnected subtrees, but that wasn't in the problem description...

Comment: An edge case with root self loops: `[[1,2],[1,1]]`

Comment: What about  `a = [[3,1],[3,2]]` ?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I assume the lowest number is at the root.  I need to ponder that.  Hopefully, a topologist will post the more general case answer.

Comment: You could probably make this faster with `for b in map(max, edges):`, though it would remain nonsensical.